# Neural network and logical gates

Tags: neural-networks, activation-functions, relu

I have a network witch consist of two fully connected layers (without bias) and a ReLu function in between. The network input is two binary numbers, and the output should be the a logical gate result:

[image: The Network]

I need to find the weights values for each one of the following logical gates: AND, OR, XOR.

In addition, I need to figure out witch one of the three gates cannot be achieved without using an activation function.

I am trying to think what the weights values should be, but I can't figure it out. I thought that $h_1$ can be $x_1+x_2$ and $h_2$ can be $x_1-x_2$ but it's not working for any of the gates.